# OBJ File is missing, all mtl files still there

Tags: mesh

[image]After I emptied my temp folder all my obj files are missing, only the mtl files remained  in my blender folder.  Does anyone have an idea what happened?

now added a screen shot showing that my obj files are exporting as 3D objects

thanks a lot!
Tom

Comment: Hi, welcome| Are you saying that after you "cleaned" (I guess delete all content?) a temp folder, some file is missing from **another** folder? Could it be that you have had some "hard links" to the files in the "temp" folder?

Comment: @ m.ardito yes I 'cleaned'/'deleted' the temp folder, so maybe that was the case. tho i would be surprised if there were 'hard links' to the temp file folder..i also noticed right now that if i export an obj file from blender it shows up as an 3D object file and mtl file in my chosen export folder? no obj file in site???

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you had some hard link to the files you deleted from the "temporary" folder... who knows why.

I just tried an export with standard parameters (below): I see an .obj and a .mtl file in a folder I created on my desktop...

[image]

Comment: all i get are .3D object file and .mtl file